# What `import` is required for symbol `Word8` to be in scope

Tags: haskell

This feels like a trivial question, but it has been nagging me for a while now: in the course of following 'Real World Haskell', I have been trying out sample code with the `Word8` data type, using the `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8` module. Most of it works fine, but I had to remove type declaration involving the symbol `Word8` as ghci would not recognize it. When using the :type ghci on some function involving this type, it is referred to as `GHC.Word.Word8`, yet replacing `Word8` by `GHC.Word.Word8` in the code doesn't improve things, and any `import` statement I have guessed around `GHC.Word.Word8` has failed. I have looked online on the hackage site which suggest `Data.Word8` but this failed to. Searching for earlier posts on this forum did not give me an answer. I am using:`GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/` on Debian 8.

Comment: [`Data.Word`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Word.html#t:Word8)?

Comment: Yep, this is perfect. Thank you !

Comment: Good to hear; I'm still learning my way around Haskell myself, but I found it via Hoogle.

Comment: Added link to my favorites, thank you.

Comment: off topic - you are using a really old version of GHC (8.0.1 is soon to be released) [here](https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc) is a ppa

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Thank you. As an aside question, I only joined the world of Linux a year ago, and while I have gained some practice at installing software from source (configure, make, make install), I am still reluctant to do this for packages which may conflict with those of my 'official' Debian repository for fear that this may corrupt my system. Am I being overly cautious, or am I right in thinking I should abstain from this sort of upgrade until I know precisely what I am doing?

Comment: am using "configure, make, sudo checkinstall" - and i am rarely using software that is not in a repo, or I only install it for my user - in "~/bin/"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition can be found in [`Data.Word`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Word.html#t:Word8).

For future reference, [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is really nice to look up where symbols come from.